# Principal bundles with no trivializable extensions

Tags: lie-groups, reductive-groups, principal-bundles

Let $Q \to M$ be a principal $G$-bundle. Given a homomorphism $\phi: G \to H$, we can ‘extend the structure group’ of $Q$ to $H$, by defining an associated principal $H$-bundle: $Q_{H} := (Q \times H)/G$.

It can happen that we have a non-trivial $G$-bundle $Q \to M$ with an extension of structure group $Q_{H}$ which is trivial. Of course, this is always possible if we take $H$ to be the trivial group. But there are also more interesting cases where $\phi$ is injective.

For example, consider a Lie group $G$ with a subgroup $P$. Then $G \to G/P$ is a principal $P$-bundle, often non-trivial. The extension to a principal $G$-bundle (using the inclusion map $P \to G$) is always trivial.

I would like to know whether it's possible to have a principal bundle such that none of its extensions are trivial. Here I restrict to extensions coming from injective homomorphisms.

As a possible candidate, consider the situation of a reductive group $G$, with a parabolic subgroup $P$, and Levi quotient $P \to L$. Now consider the associated principal $L$-bundle $G_{L} := (G \times L)/P$ which lives over $G/P$.
Does $G_{L}$ have any extensions that are trivial?

**Edit (Addressing Jason's question [below](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407382/principal-bundles-with-no-trivializable-extensions#comment1044682_407382)):** I haven't mentioned whether I am looking for holomorphic, algebraic, or continuous trivializations. My main interest is holomorphic, but the algebraic and continuous cases are also interesting. Thinking about this some more, it seems that holomorphic vs continuous are quite different stories.

In the topological setting, a principal $G$-bundle can be thought of as a map $M \to BG$, and so we are looking for embeddings $G \subset H$, such that the post-composition $M \to BH$ becomes homotopic to a constant map. So we are sort of looking for $BG \to BH$ which kills homotopy groups.

In my proposed examples above, I believe $G$ is homotopic to $G_{L}$ (since $P$ deformation retracts to $L$). Hence, I think this means that, since $G_{G}$ is trivial, $G_{L}$ also admits a trivializable extension. So the $G_{L}$ examples do not give good candidates in the topological category.

On the other hand, working in the holomorphic category, and taking the example $G = \operatorname{SL}_{2}$ and $P = B$ the Borel, we get $L = \mathbb{C}^*$, $G/P = \mathbb{CP}^1$, and $G_{L} = \mathcal{O}(-1)$. Any extension to an algebraic group can be further extended to $\operatorname{GL}_{N}$, and the result will be the frame bundle of a vector bundle of the form $\bigoplus_{i} \mathcal{O}(n_{i})$. As long as the map $\mathbb{C}^* \to \operatorname{GL}_{N}$ is non-trivial, this bundle will be non-trivial. So this indeed gives a source of examples. (This may be what Jason is alluding to in the comment [below](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407382/principal-bundles-with-no-trivializable-extensions#comment1044682_407382).)

Comment: Are you asking about continuous trivializations, holomorphic trivializations, algebraic trivializations, . . . ?  When $G$ is $\textbf{SL}_2$ and $P$ is a Borel, the Levi is the same as the maximal torus, whose associated $\textbf{SL}_2$ torsor is equivalent to $\mathcal{O}(-1)\oplus \mathcal{O}(+1)$ over the projective line.  This is smoothly trivial, but not holomorphically trivial.